# How to disable git to look files in level up folder

Tags: git

Im in a folder that is empty. But if I go to one (or more) levels up (cd ../..) there is a .git dir and this makes git think that Im in the those repository.

How to disable git to look other folders? Restrict to only this and down level.

Comment: Git considers a path part of a repository if there is a `.git` directory at the current directory or any of its parent directories. – This is by design and you cannot change this.

Comment: Not clear what you want to accomplish. A git working folder contains all subfolders as well, as @poke says, this is by design. The only way to get a subfolder not to be part of *one* repository is to create another repository inside instead.

Comment: Why do you want to clone another git repository into the folder structure of one of the git repository? What is stopping you to create a directory outside this directory?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to version the content of your target folder in a separate git repository, simply run :

```
git init
```

in this folder.

*note :* this will also "remove" this folder from the content tracked by upper git repositories.